# Charts.js display two combined line charts for last 7 days

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have 2 set of datasets I want to display in single line chart for last 7 days, and if possible only show single Y axis with max value from all data sets. I try to use time as xAxes but it is not showing up.

```
here is my code https://jsfiddle.net/e6trkxL0/
```

Comment: Please put your code in your question and don't abuse the system the way you are doing now. Since links can be altered or deleted this question will become irrelevant for future readers. Instead use the codeblock or live example to put your code in your question

Answer (score 0):

You have to place the labels for datapoints.

```js
let start = new Date(),
  end = new Date();
start.setDate(start.getDate() - 7); // set to 'now' minus 7 days.
start.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); // set to midnight.

let chart = new Chart(document.getElementById("lastSevenDaysOverview"), {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        data: [1, 4, 66, 7, 12, 3, 8],
        borderColor: '#ff3366',
        backgroundColor: '#ff3366',

      },
      {
        label: 'Dataset 2',
        data: [31, 14, 6, 71, 1, 35, 9],
        borderColor: '#880000',
        backgroundColor: '#880000',
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    interaction: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: true,
    },
    stacked: false,
    responsive: true,

    scales: {
      y: {
        type: 'linear',
        display: true,
        position: 'left',
      },
      xAxes: [{
        type: "time",
         // this is not doing much 
         // time: {
          // min: start,
          // max: end,
          // unit: "day"
        //}
      }]
    }
  }
});

chart.render();

for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  var labelDate = start;
  labelDate.setDate(start.getDate() + 1);
  chart.data.labels.push(labelDate.toLocaleString())
}

chart.update();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="lastSevenDaysOverview"></canvas>
```

Comment: Reason why his x axis are not doing much is because its configured wrong, even in your answer its not doing anything. You can check my answer why and how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

2 things, for a time axis in chart.js you need according to the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/axes/cartesian/time.html#date-adapters) a time adapter. Also you defined you x axis scales as a array which is incorrect. You need to define all scales as an object where the key of the object is the scale ID, you can read more about it in the [migration guide](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/getting-started/v3-migration.html)

For points to be mapped in the chart you also need to provide a x place which in this case needs to be the date for which the datapoint is valid.

To just show a single axis with the highest values you can let both datasets be mapped to the same y axis:

```js
let start = new Date(),
  end = new Date();
start.setDate(start.getDate() - 7); // set to 'now' minus 7 days.
start.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); // set to midnight.

new Chart(document.getElementById("lastSevenDaysOverview"), {
  type: "line",
  data: {
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Dataset 1',
        data: [{
          x: new Date('10-16-2021'),
          y: 1
        }, {
          x: new Date('10-18-2021'),
          y: 4
        }, {
          x: new Date('10-19-2021'),
          y: 66
        }],
        borderColor: '#ff3366',
        backgroundColor: '#ff3366',
      },
      {
        label: 'Dataset 2',
        data: [{
          x: new Date('10-14-2021'),
          y: 31
        }, {
          x: new Date('10-18-2021'),
          y: 14
        }, {
          x: new Date('10-19-2021'),
          y: 6
        }],
        borderColor: '#880000',
        backgroundColor: '#880000'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    interaction: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: true,
    },
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      y: {
        type: 'linear',
        display: true,
        position: 'left',
      },
      x: {
        type: "time",
        min: start,
        max: end,
        time: {
          unit: "day"
        }
      }
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="lastSevenDaysOverview"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
```